# Modifying Fiddler JSON response by Fiddler Script

Tags: c#, json, fiddler

Hi i am just trying to change a subvalue of json object,
this code works for me

```
    if(oSession.uriContains("/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2")) {          
        var j = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString()).JSONObject;
        j["args"]["foo1"]="manipulated";
        oSession.utilSetResponseBody(Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonEncode(j));
    }
```

when i check the response section at fiddler it seems fine

[image]

but when i just go to

https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2

and check the body by browser it seems body is not manipulated by fiddler. ( capturing mode is on )

is this a bug or i do something wrong?
best regards.

[image]

Comment: Typically, this means that you have the |STREAM| button depressed in Fiddler's toolbar, such that the modification is happening AFTER the response was already leaked to the client.

Comment: its solved thank you